# how to add layer of awswrangular in the aws lambda layers, awsdatawrangular not there the list of layers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

writing program on aws lambda and got an error called "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'awswrangler'", and after searching in yt, google not get any solution, how to add this perticular layer in aws lambda function.

how I  can add the awswrangular layer to aws lambda function.

Comment: Which AWS region? It is available in all AWS Commercial regions https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/2.15.0/layers.html